# fail2ban: how much time remaining on ban?

Tags: fail2ban

With fail2ban, is there a way to query how much time is remaining on an IP ban? fail2ban-client bantime shows what the original “sentence” was for, but how do I find out how much time remains before “parole”?

Answer (score 9):

According to https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/2315
and https://superuser.com/questions/1539368/how-to-get-list-banned-ip-and-its-unban-time-in-fail2ban-on-linux looks like as of fail2ban 0.11.1 there is a fail2ban-client command that will do this:

```
fail2ban-client get <JAIL> banip --with-time
```